# Sort a BindingSource which is a set of objects by a series of properties

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, sorting, datagridview

The question has been asked a lot (which I am aware of) however I have been unable to implement something which works for me specifically.

I am using Entity Framework in order to handle data interaction (and am somewhat new to the contept) with a WinForms application; this works fine and means that the `DataSource` of any DataGridView control is a list of objects.

The user is to have the ability to sort on multiple columns. For DataGridView controls which have no `DataSource` (as they're one-way and I have pulled the data straight from the DB) this is not an issue, as a custom `IComparer` class handles this sorting.

However, I appear to be unable to sort grids which have a `DataSource` where the `DataSource` is a set of objects by multiple columns.

The important thing to observe is that the `DataSource` of the DataGridView could be a list of objects of any type (Customers, Recipes, Cars etc.) as the grid could be representing data from any table in the database through objects.

The way I am getting the `DataSource` for the DataGridView control is as follows (this example is for the users in the system):

```
dtgUserList.pFormGrid.DataEntityProvider.USER_LIST
                    .Where(X => X.USER_ID > 1)
                    .Load();

dtgUserList.pFormGrid.DataSource = dtgUserList.pFormGrid.DataEntityProvider.USER_LIST.Local.ToBindingList();
```

When the `DataSource` of the DataGridView was a `DataTable` which was a direct database query, I could simply cast the `DataSource` of the DataGridView as a `BindingSource` and then set the `Sort` property to be the sorting string. For example, if sorting the user list by USER_NAME and then by PROFILE, the sort would be as follows:

```
((BindingSource)DataSource).Sort = SortArgs;
```

Where SortArgs = "USER_NAME ASC, PROFILE ASC". This could be determined simply by iterating through the columns which were sorted and extracting and concatenating the `DataPropertyName` of the column.

If I try and cast the `DataSource` of the DataGridView control which is bound to the above set of `USER_LIST` objects however, I get a compile time error indicating that the cast cannot be performed.

To try and address this, I am creating a new `BindingSource` from the existing `DataSource` in order to then try and apply the same sort logic (of just creating the sort string and then passing this to the `Sort` property of the `BindingSource`):

```
BindingSource GridBindingSource = new BindingSource(DataSource, null);
SortedGridBinding.Sort = SortArgs;
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, the `SupportsAdvancedSorting` property is always `false`, despite the `BindingSource` implementing `IBindingListView`, which is documented in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.supportsadvancedsorting(v=vs.110).aspx) article for this property.

What I am primarily trying to understand is why this property is always being set to `false`, despite the class I am using implementing the required interface to allow multi-column sorting. I have also seen a number of examples on how to implement sorting of lists of objects by multiple properties, such as [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29219/Sorting-Collections-by-Multiple-Properties) however, unless I am mis-understanding something, this still relies on a strongly typed IList input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an option you can add `System.Linq.Dynamic` reference to your project, then after using `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace, you will be able to sort an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` by passing sort column and sort order as `string`, for example:

```
var list = db.Products.ToList();
bindingSource1.DataSource = list.OrderBy("Name ASC, Price DESC").ToList();
```

**Resources**

- [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) for `System.Linq.Dynamic`. You can install the package simply using this command in package manager console: `Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic`
- [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) for `System.Linq.Dynamic`
- [Scott Guthrie's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)
  about *Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)*

Comment: Any question or idea? Any problem or success? :)

Comment: Many thanks for your input again. System,Linq.Dynamic is working out great for the initial loading from the DB however the other side with which I'm dealing is that there is a BindingSource, the DataSource of which contains a collection of entities, for example, sales orders or customers. If, in the code, I declare a strongly typed List<T> where T : the type I *know* is in the DataSource, then I can load into a List and use dynamic LINQ. However, if I try and declare it as List<object>, it says that it cannot find the fields on which I am sorting, despite both lists being the same in debugger.

Comment: Why do you want to use `List<object>`? If you want to unbox the object which is in `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` when you know it's actually a `List<Product>` it's enough to use `var data = bindingSource1.SataSource as List<Product>;`. I have used `System.Linq.Dynamic`  for such purpose (like your requirement) in Windows Forms, WCF, Web Api and ASP.NET MVC without any problem.  So let me know if you have any problem applying the solution.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I was not explaining well enough; I don't know whether it's a `List<Product>`, a `List<SalesOrder>` or a `List<Car>` at that point in time; all I know is that it **could** be a list of any of those. I am currently looking at how reflection might achieve this by determining the Type that way and then somehow instantiating a 'List<>' of the corresponding Type.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your comment well, but I think you can have a `Model` property for example of type `List<Product>` and when loading data fill the `Model` property. Then when showing data or client-side filtering or sorting, always use the Model to apply a filter or sort and then pass the result to the binding source. For example: `bindingSource.DataSource = Model.Where(...).OrderBy(...).ToList();`

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem may be me not explaining it very well; perhaps more context will help: the `DataGridView` control is supposed to have a generic `Sort` function, which I have now done with `System.Linq.Dynamic` and am intending just to use `List<T>.OrderBy()` as I have tried that out and it works well. However, the operation to sort the data in the grid needs to be able to, when called, determine that the bound objects within the grid are `List<Product>` or `List<Car>` or `List<SalesOrder>` etc. and then instantiate a `List<>` of the same type so that it can use `.OrderBy().ToList()`.

Comment: Based on comments, I suppose you want to use it some where, which you don't need the actual type of data and the data is boxed in an `object` and the only thing which you know is, it's a `List<T>`. Then you can use it this way:

    `var list = (data as IEnumerable).OrderBy("Name ASC, Price DESC");`
    `bindingSource1.DataSource = list;`

Comment: Yes, that seems to have done it; it ended up just being a one-liner: `(DataSource as BindingSource).DataSource = ((DataSource as BindingSource).List as IEnumerable).OrderBy(SortArgs);`

Comment: @Your_Unequal Good job! :)