# Filter data grid view list with the value from the search text box: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datasource

I have set up a text box to search names on my data grid but I am receiving the error: `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

```
List<Member> members = new List<Member>();

public class Member
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public Image image_url { get; set; }
}

// In a keyup event of the text box
(memberGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("name = '{0}'", searchBox.Text);
```

I have attempted to change `DataTable` to `List` or `Member`. I have also tried casting using `List/Member` in front of `DataTable` but it doesn't seem to work.

What's the best approach to this?

Edit:

This is how I add each row of data from my SQL select into the list.

```
members.Add(new Member
{
    id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
    name = reader["name"].ToString(),
    age = Convert.ToInt32(reader["age"]),
    image_url = (Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(reader["image_url"].ToString())
});
```

To add to the grid, I loop through the list and add a row per member:

```
for (int i = 0; i < members.Count; i++)
{
    memberGrid.Rows.Add(new object[]
    {
        members[i].image_url,
        members[i].name,
        members[i].age
    });
}
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4166403/656243

Comment: I don't have all of your code available but based on what you've posted I'm guessing you are setting `List<Member>` as a datasource to a `DataGrid` and latter trying to case it as `DataTable` which will be evaluated as null and that is the reason you are getting `'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` exception. Bind datagrid to DataTable and your problem should be solved.

Comment: Datasource of your DataGridView is probably a `List<T>`. It's not `DataTable`. So `memberGrid.DataSource as DataTable` is null.

Comment: What's the `DataSource` of your `memberGrid`? Show us the code which sets data source of the `DataGridView`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have updated the question with how I populate the data grid.

Comment: You are filling the database by adding rows and didn't used its data source, so `DataSource` is null.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Would I need to completely change the way I add the data into the grid to be able to get this to work?

Comment: Just load data into a `DataTable` and set it as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`. Then the filtering can be done the same way that you are trying to do.

Comment: The answer contains solutions to use a `DataTable` or a `List<T>` to show data in `DataGridView` and filter data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't set `DataSource` of `DataGridView` and it's null, then you received an exception when you used it in this statement: `(memberGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView...`.

Instead of adding rows one by one to the `DataGridView`, assign data to its `DataSource`. Then depending to the data structure which you are using, you can filter data.

You can use either of the following solutions:

- As an option, to fix the problem, you can load data into a `DataTable` and set it as `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`. Then the filtering can be done the same way that you are trying to do.
- Also if for any reason you prefer to have a `List<Member>` and apply filter on that, after loading data and converting to a `List<Member>`, keep the list in a form member field like `List<Member> members;` then for filtering using `linq`:

  ```
  dataGridView1.DataSource = members.Where(x=>x.Name ==searchBox.Text).ToList();
  ```

For more details read the following sections in the post.

**Why I receive NullReferenceException**

The following line of code will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `DataSource` is null or `DataSource` is not a `DataTable`:

```
(memberGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = ...
```

In your case, You are filling the database by adding rows and didn't used its data source, so `DataSource` is null and above code throws exception.

To find more information about how to debug `NullReferenceException`, take a look at [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/3110834).

**Load Data**

You have mentioned:

> This is how I add each row of data from my SQL select into the list.
>
> ```
> members.Add(new Member {
>       id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]),
>       name = reader["name"].ToString(), 
>       ...
> ```

It seems you are using a SQL query and a `SqlDataReader`. Then you don't need to use a `List<Member>`, a `DataTable` would be enough for you. You can change your code to the following code to load data:

```
public DataTable GetData()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var cn = @"Your Connection String";
    var cmd = @"Your Select Command";
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cn))
        da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

*Note:* If for any reason you are interested to keep working with `List<Member>`, refactor your code to return a `List<Member>` in `GetData`:

```
public List<Member> GetData()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var cn = @"Your Connection String";
    var cmd = @"Your Select Command";
    using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cn))
        da.Fill(dt);
    return dt.AsEnumerable().AsEnumerable().Select(r=>{
        id = r.Field<int>("id"),
        name = r.Field<string>("name"),
        age = r.Field<int>("age")
    }).ToList();
}
```

**Show Data in DataGridView**

You have mentioned:

> To add to the grid, I loop through the list and add a row per member:
>
> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < members.Count; i++) {
>     memberGrid.Rows.Add(new object[]
>       ...
> ```

When you load data into a `DataTable` (or even in a `List<Member>`) you don't need to add rows one by one to the `DataGridView`, just assign the data to `DataSource` property of the `DataGridView`.

To do so, you can override `OnLoad` method of the form or handle `Load` event and load data into a data table and set it as data source of the `DataGridView`:

```
DataTable dt;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    dt = LoadData();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

*Note:* If for any reason you preferred returning a `List<Member>` from `GetData`, the code will be:

```
List<Member> members;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    members = LoadData();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = members;
}
```

**Filter Data**

Then to filter data, it's enough to use `dt.DefaultView.RowFilter`:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("name = '{0}'", searchBox.Text);
```

*Note:* If for any reason you prefer to have a `List<Member>` and apply filter on that, after loading and keep the list in a form member like what I did in above sections, use `linq` to filter data:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = members.Where(x=>x.Name ==searchBox.Text).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Reza Aghaei explained how to solve problem but in case someone in future need maybe one more way to handle these situations here is how i do it.

So as mentioned problem is making `(memberGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("name = '{0}'", searchBox.Text);`

There are 2 reasons why it may happen.

- You `DataSource` is not assigned so it `is null`
- You assigned object with other type than `DataTable` and then you try to cast it "back" to `DataTable` so it returns null

For flawless flow ALWAYS bind data to data source and manipulate it through it.
Here is how i am doing it in my datagridviews.

- First i try to load data directly into DataTable

So if you are loading it from SQL just use `DataAdapter` and fill `DataTable`

```
using(SqlConnetion....)
{
    con.Open();
    using(SqlDataAdapter da ....)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        dataGridView.DataSource = dt;

        //I use this method often because every change i am doing is directly into database and then i just refresh dgv if i need it by loading data again.
    }
}
```

If loading data directly do `DataTable` is for some reason hard for you (need to create datatable yourself and populate it with foreach but too many columns or something like that) or you want to manipulate data inside your code but not in `DataTable` you can use `List<T>`

So simply create object

```
public class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public string LicencePlate { get; set; }
    public doube HP { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
    }
}
```

then let's say we need to load cars from `jsonString` we do `List<Car> myCars = JsonConverter.Deserialize<List<Car>>(stringFromWebForExample);`

and now we have got list in which we can manipulate but need to put it into datagridview. Again we could do it just by `dataGridView.DataSource = myCars` but `DataTable` is more functional than `List` when it comes to displaying in datagridview so what i do is convert that list to datatable with this code:

```
public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
{
    PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
       TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    foreach (T item in data)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
}
```

and just call it `dataGridView.DataSource = myCars.ConvertToDataTable();`

So that are two practical ways of handing data and displaying it in `DataGridView`

Comment: While users can use linq for filtering a `List<T>`, if they are interested to perform filtering using string filters, it's better to use `System.Linq.Dynamic` like what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37798899/3110834).

Comment: Also in cases like what OP has asked, since they can load data into `DataTable` from the beginning, they don't need to convert data to list and then for filtering [convert generic list to datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/564366/3110834)