# Passing all items to another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

I am passing to another form the items of variás selections in the datagrid, however I need the second Form opens once only. I put the Form call inside the

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvcontasreceber.SelectedRows)
    {

       SqlConnection conConexao1 = clsdb.AbreBanco();
       SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select dbo.empresas.id, dbo.empresas.razao_social from empresas inner join dbo.pessoa_empresa on dbo.pessoa_empresa.empresa_id = dbo.empresas.id inner join dbo.pessoa on dbo.pessoa.id = dbo.pessoa_empresa.pessoa_id where dbo.pessoa.id ='" + lblid.Text + "'", conConexao1);
       SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr1.HasRows == true)
        {
            if (dr1.Read())
            {
               var item = new clsItens
               {
                  PessoaId = txtid.Text,
                  EmpresaId = int.Parse(dr1[0].ToString()),
                  RazaoSocial = dgvcontasreceber[0, linhaAtual].Value.ToString()
               };

               items.Add(item);
             }
         }

         dr1.Close();
         cmd1.Clone();
         conConexao1.Close();

   }
   FormRecebimento abrir = new FormRecebimento(items);
   abrir.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: The problem is that you are opening the second Form several times, I want it to open only once but pass all the foreach data.

Comment: But your FormRecebimento can only accept 1 row of data, how would it show the data for all rows?

Comment: This is true, I tried to pass through a prorem array even though I was passing a value. That's why I'd like to know how to move on to another form.

Comment: You have to change your FormRecebimento to accept many rows. Then you can pass all the rows to the form and you won't need a foreach loop anymore. But your FormRecebimento will have to look very different if it must display a set of rows instead of a single one.

Comment: but how would I do that? Do you have an example you can pass?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180022/discussion-between-guillaume-cr-and-renato).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first answer says, you need to find a way to FormRecebimento receives a collection (that can be an array, list, IEnumerable, etc), and use these values insidethe form according what you want.

Maybe you can have some inspiration from this:

```
class Item
{
    public string PessoaId { get; set };
    public int EmpresaId { get; set };
    public string RazaoSocial { get; set };
}

class FormRecebimento
{
    private List<Item> items;

    public FormRecebimento(List<Item> items)
    {
        this.items = items;
        this.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        /* Iterate over Item list and set the values you want
        pessoaid = int.Parse(txtid.Text);
        id_empresa = int.Parse(dgvcontasreceber[16, linhaAtual].Value.ToString());
        idrec.Text = dgvcontasreceber[0, linhaAtual].Value.ToString();
        */
    }
}

//... 

List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgvcontasreceber.SelectedRows)
{

   SqlConnection conConexao1 = clsdb.AbreBanco();
   SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select dbo.empresas.id, dbo.empresas.razao_social from empresas inner join dbo.pessoa_empresa on dbo.pessoa_empresa.empresa_id = dbo.empresas.id inner join dbo.pessoa on dbo.pessoa.id = dbo.pessoa_empresa.pessoa_id where dbo.pessoa.id ='" + lblid.Text + "'", conConexao1);
   SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

   if (dr1.HasRows == true)
   {
      if (dr1.Read())
      {
         var item = new Item
         { 
            PessoaId = txtid.Text, 
            EmpresaId = int.Parse(dr1[0].ToString()),
            RazaoSocial = dgvcontasreceber[0, linhaAtual].Value.ToString()
         }
         items.add(item);
      }
   }

   dr1.Close();
   cmd1.Clone();
   conConexao1.Close();
}

FormRecebimento abrir = new FormRecebimento(items);
abrir.ShowDialog();
```

I couldn't really use the correct 'labels' on variables names because I didn't  understand very well your code, so I really recommend to take a look to 'Clean Code' stuffs on internet, I'm sure it will help you a lot :)

Tip: http://www.macoratti.net/17/05/c_codlimp1.htm (ptBR as I belive you speak portuguese too)

Comment: When I initialize the counter in Form Receive, an error occurs saying:

Error CS0051 Inconsistent Accessibility: Parameter type "List <FormRecebimento.Item>" is less accessible than the "FormRecebimento.FormRecebimento(List<FormRecebimento.Item>)"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0051
I believe setting the classes as 'public' should solve this problem, ex: 'public class Item'

Comment: So it of the error of conversion of the call of FormReception, that is to say it does not recognize the object Item

Comment: Look at the error you can not convert from: "System.Collections.Generic.List<Aplicacao.Item>" to "System.Collections.Generic.List<Aplicacao.FormRecebimento.Item>"

Comment: It seems you are using different types in the list  'Aplicacao.Item' to 'Aplicacao.FormRecebimento.Item'.
My suggestion: Update your question with all  your code related to the issue, including the source for FormRecebimento, and other classes. This will help us to offer help.

Comment: It's almost working, the problem being in this line: `dgvcontasreceber [0, currentLine] .Value.ToString ()`
  is always taking the value of the last. What should I do to get the value of each selected item?

Comment: Can you post what your foreach looks like now? Maybe you are using wrong attributes...

Comment: It is the same as your example, it percore the selected lines correctly, but only takes the last line value selected. I edited the question, it's the way it is now.

Comment: Ok, i think the problem is with the variable 'linhaAtual', that probably you are setting only once. Try to refactor this part, because I think you are doing some missunderstanding there, you should be using the variable 'row' of the forEach in this case. Take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: My currentLine is this way: currentLine =`int.Parse (e.RowIndex.ToString ());`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, FormRecebimento needs a single pessoaid, a single id_empresa and a single idrec to work. If you must pass multiple values to the form, you have to replace those properties with a new property of type `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`. If we were to call this new property inputRows, then your code would look something like this:

```
FormRecebimento abrir = new FormRecebimento();
abrir.inputRows = dgvcontasreceber.SelectedRows;
abrir.ShowDialog();
```

How you implement the display of the inputRows is outside the scope of this question, but at least this should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: In the other form I created public IEnumerable <DataGridViewRow> inputRows ;, but the conversion error in the first form

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not using `SQL` safe way.

Second thing is you create one instance of form with variable type of let's say `int` and then you overwrite that variable every time in foreach loop.

I will now write finished code for you since this code is complete mess.

First of all create new `class` which will look something like this:

```
public YourNewClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string razao_social { get; set; } //I am guessing this one is string in your database

    public YourNewClas()
    {
    }
}
```

Now inside your new form you want to open (`FormRecebimento`) create this variable

```
public List<YourNewClass> listOfMyNewClass;
```

And now you current code rewrite like this:

```
FormRecebimento abrir = new FormRecebimento();
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgvcontasreceber.SelectedRows)
{
    using(SqlConnection conConexao1 = clsdb.AbreBanco()) //Use using since it will dispose of connection automatically after it finishes using it
    {
        conConexao1.Open(); // you do not have this line so maybe it is inside your function but not sure so i put it here
        using(SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select dbo.empresas.id, dbo.empresas.razao_social from empresas inner join dbo.pessoa_empresa on dbo.pessoa_empresa.empresa_id = dbo.empresas.id inner join dbo.pessoa on dbo.pessoa.id = dbo.pessoa_empresa.pessoa_id where dbo.pessoa.id = @ID", conConexao1))
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lblid.Text); //Use parameters when building SqlCommand since it is safer way

            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr1.HasRows == true) // I am never using this one but just if(dr1.Read()) or while(dr1.Read()) and never had problem but i left it there  for you
            {
                if (dr1.Read())
                {
                    //We create new object type of your custom class and add it to new forms (which we created but haven't shown yet) list
                    abrir.listOfMyNewClass.Add(new YourNewClass{ Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr1[0]), razao_social = dr1[1].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    abrir.ShowDialog();
}
```

This code will create your new form OUTSIDE FOREACH LOOP (so only one time) which will have public accessible variable called `listOfMyNewClass` which is type of `List<MynewClas>`

Then INSIDE FOREACH LOOP we will populate `listOfMyNewClass` inside new form with `Add()` method (so we will not overwrite that variable every time)

Then OUTSIDE FOREACH LOOP we will show newly created form with populated `List<YourNewClass> listOfMyNewClass`;

To manipulate that variable inside new form simply read everything about [System.Collections.Generic.List here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and if you want to use that list as DataTable look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237243/filter-data-grid-view-list-with-the-value-from-the-search-text-box-object-refe/52279547#52279547)

Comment: I did not understand this part:
 ` open.listOfMyNewClass.Add (new YourNewForm {Id = Convert.ToInt32 (dr [0]), social_role = dr [1] .ToString ();`

Why would we have to Create a new Form? And where does the "dr" come from?

Comment: @Renato Sorry. It was from head. It shoud be `dr1` instead of `dr`. And about `open.ListOfMyNewClass.....` in my code i did not use `open` but `abrir` (name use called your object which is your newly created form)

Comment: Even with the conversion of the conversion error of the object to the class.

Comment: Error CS1503 Argument 1: Can not convert from "Application.YourNewForm" to "Aplication.YourNewClass"

Comment: Insted of `YourNewForm` in that part of code use `YourNewForm`. Mistake in writing. Also rename classes. Those were just my names so you understand better.

Comment: I created a Form called YourNewForm only for the same test level and the class with the same name.